# ViewNotFoundException on Shared Hosting Cpanel + Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

1. I have create a yii2 project which runs prefectly on my Windows localhost machine.
2. I am using XAMPP on windows machine to work on Yii2 application.
3. But Since I have deployed application successfully on Cpanel Linux Shared Hosting, I am unable open the pages on my website.
4. Below is the error on Shared Hosting backend/web logs;

   ```
   [error][yii\base\ViewNotFoundException] exception 'yii\base\ViewNotFoundException' with message 

   'The view file does not exist: /home/xyz/public_html/nse/backend/views/site/student\student_list.php' 
   in /home/xyz/public_html/nse/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php:229
   ```

Same stuff works fine on my local machine. **Any help?**

Comment: Is your local machine WIndows and server is Linux?

Comment: Yes Sir. that is right.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case-sensitive problem.

Check if all the names and corresponding files are saved the same way i.e. view in `student_list.php` should be called `->render('student_list')` and not something like `->render('Student_list')`.

The same thing with folder names and classes names.

**UPDATE**
The error shows you are calling the view with backslash instead of slash so you should correct it.

While there is no big difference when using them in paths on Windows you should use it properly on Linux.

Quick explanation from [quora.com](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-slash-and-the-backslash):

This is how both the slashes are used :

Forward Slash `/`

- `/` is used in the file system of UNIX (and by extension, Linux and OS X).
- `/` is the standard symbol for 'division' in almost all programming languages.
- `/` is also used in the URLs as a separator.

Backslash `\`

- `\` is used in the file system of DOS and Windows.
- `\` is used as escape sequence (\n,\t etc.)
- `\` is used in UNIX File Systems to indicate to the Terminal, White spaces in path of a directory. (While enclosing absolute text within double quotes is also followed).

As for their history , WikiPedia is your friend here

> The slash goes back to the days of ancient Rome. In the early modern period, in the Fraktur script, which was widespread through Europe in the Middle Ages, one slash (/) represented a comma, while two slashes (//) represented a dash. The two slashes eventually evolved into a sign similar to the equals sign (=), then being further simplified to a single dash (–)

The origin of the backslash is quite recent, though

> Bob Bemer introduced the "\" character into ASCII on September 18, 1961, as the result of character frequency studies. In particular the \ was introduced so that the ALGOL boolean operators ∧ (AND) and ∨ (OR) could be composed in ASCII as "/\" and "/" respectively. Both these operators were included in early versions of the C programming language supplied with Unix V6, Unix V7 and more currently BSD 2.11.

For more info see [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I have mentioned, I have ensured that file structure and naming conventions are same on local machine and shared hosting linux server. All I have done is zipped my project on local machine and extraced it on my server, thats it. Same studd works on windows local machine.

Comment: Are you calling the view exactly like this `student\student_list`?

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong. The error suggest you called it like `student\student_list` but you say you use `student/student_list` (with proper slash).

Comment: thank you so much for your time. Yes, you are right initially it was as it is seen in my question, later till you were responding , I did some hit and trial method and Voila! I tried calling "return \Yii::$app->controller->render('student/student_list', [....]); " instead of " return $this->render('student\student_list', [..]); ", it worked. I can definitely upvote and rate you, if you could help me explain the difference between the above two calls.

Comment: You said in answer it is case sensitive problem, I agree! but I am not getting page on using $this_render(), rather I get page on \Yii::$app->controller->render().

Comment: You mean rather `$this->render()`. This is the call to the same method.

Comment: yeah but call works only if I use \Yii::$app->controller->render()

Comment: You don't say anything about where you call it from. `$this->render()` works from inside controller method.

Comment: Everything that I do is inside controller method. I know $this->render() should work from inside, but even I am confused how this is not working on shared hosting server. I had to use other way round :(